# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl' - angular4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

there are lots of blogs already posted for this error but none is specified for angular4.

I am adding and removing dynamic controls on the form

**add controls to the form during intialization**

```js
    ngOnInit() {
    
        this.lienHolder = this._fb.group({
          emailAddress: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
          policyDetails: this._fb.array([
            this.initPolicyTemplate(),
          ])
        });
    
      }

     initPolicyTemplate() {
        return this._fb.group({
          policyNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("(^[^0][A-Z]{1}[0-9]*$)")]],
          vinNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{6}$')]],
        });
      }
```

**adding more control by calling this method**

```js
     addPolicyTemplate() {
        const control = <FormArray>this.lienHolder.controls['policyDetails'];
        control.push(this.initPolicyTemplate());
      }
```

**removing controls from the form**

```js
      removePolicyTemplate(i: number) {  
        const control = <FormArray>this.lienHolder.controls['policyDetails'];
        control.removeAt(i);
      }
```

but when i build the code i get error like this

[image]

this is my html

```html
      <div formArrayName="policyDetails">
            <div *ngFor="let _policy of lienHolder.controls.policyDetails.controls; let i=index">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-head">
                  <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right" *ngIf="lienHolder.controls.policyDetails.controls.length > 1" (click)="removePolicyTemplate(i)"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div [formGroupName]="i">
                    <address [policyGroup]="lienHolder.controls.policyDetails.controls[i]"></address>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I am not able to resolve this issue. i have followed [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2) blog to come up with the dynamic control

**UPDATE 1**

when i changed my .ts code like this

```js
    get DynamicFormControls() {
    
        return <FormArray>this.lienHolder.get('policyDetails');
      }
```

and the HTML code like this

```html
     <div formArrayName="policyDetails">
            <div *ngFor="let _policy of DynamicFormControls.controls ; let i=index" style="position: relative">
              <add-policy-details [policyGroup]="lienHolder.controls.policyDetails.controls[i]"></add-policy-details>
              <div class="remove-btn" (click)="removePolicyTemplate(i)" *ngIf="lienHolder.controls.policyDetails.controls.length > 1">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

it was working, and i was able to compile the file in t he production mode, using the command

> ng build --target=production --environment=prod

but from the past few days, i am facing the same error and not able to compile it in the production mode, i have not updated any of my application

node version - v6.11.1

npm version - 3.10.10

angular version - 4.0

dont know what exactly is causing the error.

Comment: try using this.lienHolder.get('policyDetails').removeAt(i);...same for the add control

Comment: i tried that and i am getting the same error

Comment: in some blogs it has asked me to add  [formGroupName]="i", but still i am facing the same error

Comment: sorry my bad ..try ..lienHolder.controls.get('policyDetails').length...in the template..thats where its giving the error

Comment: why are you using lienHolder.controls.policyDetails.controls.length ??

Comment: i want it just to show the close button, i tried this as well but i got error
lienHolder['controls'].policyDetails['controls'].length

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152173/discussion-between-lijin-durairaj-and-vikhyath-maiya).

Comment: length is the length of the content ?

Answer (score 20):

After digging deep found the solution [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6099).When you are doing the production build,you have to use the problem can be fixed by giving your component a get method:

```
get formData() { return <FormArray>this.lienHolder.get('policyDetails'); }
```

and then in your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let _policy of formData.controls ; let i=index">
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: i thank you from the deep of my heart, GOD bless you

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: link:
angular.io/api/forms/…
github.com/angular/…

Comment: i am getting the same error from the past few days, eventhough i have changed nothing on the code

Comment: That's the only solution i have which was working..you have messed something in other places ..

Comment: Hats off Sir. You saved my day. I thank you from the deep of my heart, GOD bless you

Comment: Thanks!. I received the same error when i build my app with --aot. With this solution i have built my angular 5 application successfully.

Answer (score 14):

I too faced the same issue on `ng build` but simply fixed with [],

```
*ngFor="let _policy of DynamicFormControls['controls'] ; let i=index"
```

use the above line instead of the below one

```
 *ngFor="let _policy of DynamicFormControls.controls ; let i=index"
```

Comment: This did the trick for me.  Simple is almost always better.  +1 from me.  In my case I was using Angular 5.

Comment: @Muthu thanks this worked for me. But could you please explain why it's working like that? What is the difference?

Comment: This is actually a simple solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Sonja - latest answer on this thread might answer your question

Answer (score 4):

```
getArrayControls() {
    return (<FormArray>this.sampleForm.get('formArr')).controls;
  }

<div *ngFor="let elem of getArrayControls(); let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
  <input formControlName="sampleElementOfArr">
</div>
```

UPDATE:

> Type assertion using the '<>' syntax is forbidden. Use the 'as' syntax instead

```
getArrayControls() {
    return (this.sampleForm.get('formArr') as FormArray).controls;
}
```

read more about [Dynamically Creating Form Fields With FormArray](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/)

Comment: Can you add some words explaining your answer?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: when is providing the right answer not good enough? when it is posted in sadoverflow

Comment: This is a great idea. I've just updated an answer a little bit.

Comment: For a nested Reactive Form it's creating performance issues. is there any better way ?

Answer (score 3):

In my case problem was I mentioned the return type of function as FormArray. I removed the return type now my getter method looks like this

```
 get eventExtraDetailsArray(){
    return this.addEventExtraForm.get('regDetails') as FormArray;
  }
```

and in the HTML I modified the code to something like this

```
<div formArrayName="regDetails">
          <div *ngFor="let eventCharge of addEventExtraForm['controls'].regDetails['controls']; let regIdx = index"
            [formGroupName]="regIdx">
 </div>
</div>
```

Now the production build works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Square brackets **`[]`** and Single quotes  **`['controls']`** in this case, should fix the issue. Also when you have to iterate over 2 times `controls`. Here is a good answer to this kind of topic: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets).

This wasn't working for me:

`let brand of productsForm.controls.brands.controls; ...`

changing it to:

`let brand of productsForm['controls'].brands['controls']; ...`

removed the error.

> Square bracket notation allows access to properties containing special characters and selection of properties using variables

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it's a strange bug although the class `FormGroup` contain a filed named `controls`
But you can try this out:
**Inside a loop:**
`<div *ngFor="let _policy of formData['controls'] ; let i=index">`

**When you want to get a specific control:**

```
<div *ngIf="form.get('myCntrol').touched && form.get('myCntrol').errors"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this issue is addressed on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6099). easiest way out is using yourFormArray['controls'] instead of yourFormArray.controls in *ngFor, or if you have a get accessor you can access the controls using that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `push` and `removeAt` methods:

```
// to push form group
const firstArray = this.invoiceForm.get('invoiceList') as FormArray;
const secondArray = firstArray.controls[j].get('packingList') as FormArray;
secondArray.push(this.initPackingList());

// to remove form group
const firstArray = this.invoiceForm.get('invoiceList') as FormArray;
const secondArray = firstArray.controls[j].get('packingList') as FormArray;
secondArray.removeAt(deletingIndex);
```